# rabbitmq binding same queue with multiple binding keys

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-c

All,

I am trying to bind a queue with multiple binding keys. However, not all keys are known upfront. So, I do `amqp_queue_bind` with one known key and then `amqp_basic_consume` and later `amqp_queue_bind` again whren second key is known.

The second `amqp_queue_bind` gets stuck and on getting core of my process using SIGSEGV, I see following stack trace:

```
poll
recv_with_timeout
wait_frame_inner
amqp_simple_rpc
amqp_simple_rpc_decoded
amqp_queue_bind
```

Do I need to do `amqp_basic_cancel` and re-do `amqp_basic_consume` if I want to add a binding key later?

Comment: I posted this problem at [link](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Make-queue-bind-after-basic-consume-rabbitmq-c-td27879.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake that I had made and solution:

Here is the app flow:

There is a message processing thread:

```
amqp_exchange_declare 
amqp_queue_declare 
while (1) { 
  if (consume_done) { 
    amqp_maybe_release_buffers 
    amqp_consume_message 
    app specific processing. 
  } 
}
```

This is main app thread: 
On getting to know a binding key, which happens later:

```
amqp_queue_bind 
if (!consume_done) { 
  amqp_basic_consume 
  consume_done 
}
```

There are multiple binding keys learnt at a later stage and so the above routine gets called multiple times in main app thread context.

The first time biding is successful and I also get messages. But second time `amqp_queue_bind` call hangs.

Here, the problem is message processing thread is doing `amqp_consume_message` with infinite timeout and we should not expect `amqp_queue_bind` to go through from main thread in this condition.

The solution is to call `amqp_queue_bind` only when `amqp_consume_message` is not waiting for messages.

It now seems it is so silly of me to have made this mistake.